# ¿Obtener el valor de base de datos en un select de html?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Como se puede hacer esto que que se muestra en el **value** pero con un `select` que trae los valores de la base de datos

Como el siguente ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="measure" class="form-control{{ 
$errors->has('measure') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" 
value="{{$food->measure}}" 
placeholder="Ingrese la porción" required>
```

Answer (score 2):

Intenta de esta manera:

Esta de mas que esto debe ir dentro de un ciclo que recorra todas la filas que trae el query

```
<select name="measure" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('measure') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}">
  //valor por defecto que es omitido al capturar
  <option value="">Selecciona la Porcion</option>
  <option value="{{$food->measure}}">{{$food->measure}}</option>
</select>
```